# Unemployment benefit: living in Canada, have worked in Germany

Tags: germany, canada, benefits, employment-agreement, insurance

I have worked for 1 year and 3 months in Germany, and I was entitled to unemployment insurance in Germany up to six months with %60-%70 of my salary. I have recently moved to Canada, and I am wondering if I can file for an unemployment insurance in Canada?

Answer (score 3):

Only if you worked for a Canadian company or government while in Germany:

> If you work outside Canada for a Canadian company or the Canadian government, you are usually covered by EI. You are not insured by the EI program if your job is covered by the country in which you are working.

[source](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/ei/ei-outside-canada.html)

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you entitled for EI at Canada currently

But there are several programs for individuals not entitled to EI

You should check cra.gc.ca website, personal account